# How to apply a custom rolling function to pandas groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to calculate the daily sales from average sales using the following function:

```
def derive_daily_sales(avg_sales_series, period, first_day_sales):
    """
    derive the daily sales from previous_avg_sales start date to current_avg_sales end date
    for detail formula, please refer to README.md

    @avg_sales_series: an array of avg  sales(e.g. 2020-08-04 to 2020-08-06)
    @period: the averaging period in days (e.g. 30 days, 90 days)
    @first_day_sales: the sales at the first day of previous_avg_sales
    """

    x_n1 = avg_sales_series[-1]*period - avg_sales_series[0]*period + first_day_sales

    return x_n1
```

The `avg_sales_series` is supposed to be a pandas series.

The dataframe looks like the following:

```
date, customer_id, avg_30_day_sales
12/08/2020, 1, 30
13/08/2020, 1, 40
14/08/2020, 1, 40
12/08/2020, 2, 20
13/08/2020, 2, 40
14/08/2020, 2, 30
```

I would like to first groupby `customer_id` and sort by `date`. Then, get the rolling window of size 2. And apply the custom function `derive_daily_sales` assuming that `period`=30 and `first_day_sales` equal to the first `avg_30_day_sales`.

I tried:

```
df_sales_grouped = df_sales.sort_values('date').groupby(['customer_id','date'])]

df_daily_sales['daily_sales'] = df_sales_grouped['avg_30_day_sales'].rolling(2).apply(derive_daily_sales, axis=1, period=30, first_day_sales= df_sales['avg_30_day_sales'][0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not group by the date since you want to roll over that column, so the grouping should be:

```
df_sales_grouped = df_sales.sort_values('date').groupby('customer_id')
```

Next, what you actually want to do is `apply` a rolling window on each group in the dataframe. So you need to use `apply` twice, once on the grouped dataframe and once on each rolling window. This can be done as follows:

```
rolling_arguments = {'period': 30, 'first_day_sales': df_sales['avg_30_day_sales'][0]}
df_sales['daily_sales'] = df_sales_grouped['avg_30_day_sales'].apply(
    lambda g: g.rolling(2).apply(derive_daily_sales, kwargs=rolling_arguments))
```

For the given input data, the result is:

```
      date  customer_id  avg_30_day_sales  daily_sales
12/08/2020            1                30          NaN
13/08/2020            1                40        330.0
14/08/2020            1                40         30.0
12/08/2020            2                20          NaN
13/08/2020            2                40        630.0
14/08/2020            2                30       -270.0
```

Comment: But I got a keyError:-1. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I solved it by using `.iloc` in the function. The input is not an array but a pandas series.

Comment: @JOHN: Correct, doing it this way would give an pandas series as input to `derive_daily_sales`. If an array is needed, you could use `.values` on the input (or just handle it as a series as you did, i.e., with `iloc`).